# How to prevent Github Desktop from opening when I open Rstudio on Windows

Tags: github, rstudio

After I downloaded Github desktop, everytime when I open Rstudio, Github desktop starts installing and running. I don't know how to stop it. Did anyone experience this before, or know what I should do?

My system is windows.

Thanks!